# how to properly create a library project with Angular CLI 7.0.0-RC2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

:) I installed `@angular/cli@next` globally with yarn in order to create an angular7 project.

I'm trying to create a library project to add several libraries that I wrote that I want to use in several projects.

I created the library project with the command `ng new tuxin-libs --style=scss --experimental-ivy` and types `No` on adding Routing since it's gonna be just a library project.

then I entered `tuxin-libs` and created a library with `ng generate library cars --prefix=tuxin` and created a component called `car-type` with `ng generate component car-type --project=cars`

I don't need the main cars component so I deleted the `cars.component.ts` and `cars.component.spec.ts` file
and removed `export * from './lib/cars.component';` from `public_api.ts` and added my code.

now I use `@angular/material`, `apollo-angular` and `ngx-webstorage-service`. and I'm really confused on how to add it to my library project

some say to add it as peer dependency. so I entered `projects/cars` and I tried installing these libraries as peer dependencies with the following commands:

```
yarn add --peer @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
yarn add --peer apollo-angular   apollo-angular-link-http   apollo-link   apollo-client   apollo-cache-inmemory   graphql-tag   graphql
yarn add --peer ngx-webstorage-service
```

then when I try to build the `cars` module by entering the root directory of my library project and execute `ng build cars` I get

```
BUILD ERROR
Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
    at ProviderElementContext._getDependency (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11504:22)
    at /Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11449:64
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11449:30
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ProviderElementContext._getOrCreateLocalProvider (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11427:67)
    at /Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11325:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new ProviderElementContext (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11322:53)
    at TemplateParseVisitor.visitElement (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15093:35)
```

when I try instead to add it as regular dependencies, same yarn commands as before just without the `--peer` parameters, and then try to compile the `cars` library I get:

```
Building Angular Package
Building entry point 'cars'
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
No name was provided for external module 'graphql-tag' in output.globals – guessing 'gql'
No name was provided for external module 'apollo-angular' in output.globals – guessing 'i1'
No name was provided for external module 'ngx-webstorage-service' in output.globals – guessing 'ngxWebstorageService'
Minifying UMD bundle
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
Distributing npm packages with 'dependencies' is not recommended. Please consider adding @angular/animations to 'peerDependencies' or remove it from 'dependencies'.

BUILD ERROR
Dependency @angular/animations must be explicitly whitelisted.
Error: Dependency @angular/animations must be explicitly whitelisted.
    at Object.keys.forEach.dep (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:125:23)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at checkNonPeerDependencies (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:119:44)
    at /Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:93:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:3:12)
    at writePackageJson (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:74:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ufkfir/projects/wd-proj/tuxin-libs/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ng-v5/entry-point/write-package.transform.js:41:11)
```

this errors happens exactly the same using angular6 cli and not the latest angular7... but anyhow.. now I'm using 7 so I want it to be fixed here :)

I tried also using `ng add @angular/material --project=cars` and `ng add apollo-angular --project=cars`, in both cases I get `Multiple projects are defined; please specify a project name` although I did specify a project.

any ideas?

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok.. so I needed to add the relevant libraries as peer dependencies in the package.json of the cars project, and to add it as regular dependencies to the main library project.

that's it :) simple